# How to open 4 Bootstrap modals upon one another?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I've a web app project which needs to open multilevel Bootstrap modal upon one another but after opening 3 modals, the browser hangs. Is there any custom code to do so or to avoid hanging probelm?

Comment: post relative codes, without code can't help much

Answer (score 0):

Stop. I think you should reconsider the usability of such a solution.

Would you be happy, as a user, to be on a website with **4 different modals** opened at the same time (even if nested!)? Wouldn't it be a bit confusing?

I understand somebody else might have told you that that's what they want. But please think again your design pattern.

In general, [modal windows should be used sparingly](http://uxmovement.com/forms/best-practices-for-modal-windows/).

Hope this helps.